# How do I recover ros root setup.bash?

Tags: ros, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I accidentally deleted the setup.bash and all other root files from "/opt/ros/noetic/".

Is there any way to recover that without reinstalling the ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382432/how-do-i-recover-ros-root-setup.bash?/) by [JoaoPedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/12316/joaopedro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2021-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(I'm sssuming you've installed ROS using `apt` here)

This seems similar to #q257332, and you could use a similar approach to figure out which package provides those files (or any file really):

```
dpkg -S /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
```

which returns this for me:

```
ros-noetic-catkin: /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
```

you can then reinstall that using:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ros-noetic-catkin
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoaoPedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/12316/joaopedro/) on 2021-07-14**:
Thank you.

This approach correctly restores the files. However, once I didn't have the file anymore, figuring out that it comes from ros-noetic-catkin is not possible without your suggestion. Does it have another method (website or similar) to verified this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-14**:
It's a generated file, so I don't believe you would be able to find it anywhere necessarily.